# Applescript XML "Invalid Index" with CDATA

Tags: xml, applescript

Parsing the following XML with the following script throws an "Invalid Index" error. I've isolated it down to the fact that the `CDATA` isn't wrapped inside of a tag. It appears that the script counts the `CDATA` as a valid element in the initial read but doesn't use it in subsequent reads, thus throwing off the index and selecting the wrong element.

How can I get around this?

example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
  <info>Some info</info>
  <![CDATA[Yo]]>
  <books>
    <book country="US">
      <name>The Secret Lives of Cats</name>
      <publisher>Feline Press</publisher>
    </book>
  </books>
</library>
```

The script:

```c
tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file "~/Downloads/example.xml"
        set books to every XML element of XML element "books" of XML element "library" whose name is "book"
        repeat with a from 1 to length of books
            set theBook to item a of books
            tell theBook
                name of every XML element
                name of every XML attribute
                value of every XML attribute
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Note, the example is a partly modified version of https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WorkwithXML.html

If you remove the `<![CDATA[Yo]]>` part and run the script, you'll see that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **referenced object**, like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file "~/Downloads/example.xml"
        set ref_books to a reference to (XML elements of XML element "books" of XML element "library" whose name is "book")
        repeat with theBook in ref_books
            tell theBook
                name of every XML element
                name of every XML attribute
                value of every XML attribute
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Or use the `tell` block on the **whose clause**, like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file "~/Downloads/example.xml""
        tell (XML elements of XML element "books" of XML element "library" whose name is "book")
            repeat with theBook in it
                tell theBook
                    name of every XML element
                    name of every XML attribute
                    value of every XML attribute
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```